# Cómo implementar un websocket PHP sin compartir datos entre navegadores

Tags: php, websocket

voy al grano.

**CONTEXTO.** PHP 7.4.10, Apache 2.4.35 y MySQL 5.7.25, [Librería Ratchet 0.4.3](http://socketo.me/)

**OBJETIVO.** Tengo dos fechas, una de inicio y otra de fin almacenadas en una base de datos MySQL. Quiero hacer visible un tag HTML (por ejemplo un DIV) si la fecha actual entra en el rango de esas fechas. Eso es todo.

**CÓMO LO QUIERO HACER.** Quiero usar websockets. Encontré que lo mejor es usar la librería Ratchet para PHP. Como las fechas de inicio y fin pueden cambiar en cualquier momento, se me ocurre hacer un bucle JS que itere cada 5 segundos, y en cada iteración que vaya a la base de datos en busca de las fechas de inicio y fin y luego corroborar si la fecha actual entra en rango. Si entra, entonces simplemente mostrar el DIV.

**CÓMO LO ESTOY HACIENDO.** Hay muchos ejemplos online de websockets con PHP, pero todos los que encontré eran de chats, así que tomé como base este: https://github.com/durgesh-sahani/chatroom-php-mysql-ratchet que funciona bien. Lo modifiqué y finalmente logré que cumpliera con mi objetivo.

**PROBLEMA.** Como el código original del ejemplo que tomé es de un chat, todos los mensajes que imprimo en la consola del navegador se muestran también en todas las consolas de todas las pestañas/navegadores abiertos. No quiero este comportamiento, porque mi desarrollo no es un chat. Ojalá puedan echarme una mano con este problema. A continuación pongo mi código (omití todo el código que consideré innecesario)

Este es el contenido de server.php (que es el que ejecuto desde la consola de mi SO: php server.php):

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Fechas;
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Fechas()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );
    $server->run();
```

Esto está dentro del index.php:

```
let conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    setInterval(function(){
        conn.send('getFechas');
    }, 5000);
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    // Recupero los datos recibidos del servidor. Con estos datos disponibles del lado del cliente, ya es fácil mostrar/ocultar un DIV según mis necesidades (por brevedad, no pongo ese código).
    let fechaInicio = null;
    let fechaFin = null;
    let json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    for(let key in json) {
        if (key==='fecha1') fechaInicio = json[key];
        else if (key==='fecha2') fechaFin = json[key];
    }
};

conn.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('Conexión websocket cerrada!');
};
```

Esta es la clase PHP (Fechas.php) encargada de hacer el trabajo en el servidor (por brevedad omito los eventos onclose y onerror):

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use \PDO;
class Fechas implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage; // Supongo que aquí es donde comienza el código de aquello que ocasiona los efectos que no deseo, ya que como mi desarrollo no es un chat, no tiene por qué existir un "CLIENTS". Pero no sé cómo quitar esta línea y que el desarrollo siga funcionando.
        echo 'Servidor Ratchet iniciado...';
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        try {
            $fechas = array();
            // Me conecto a la BD y recupero los datos que necesito
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM conf WHERE id=? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');
            if ($stmt->execute([1])) {
                if($stmt->rowCount() === 1) {
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $fechas['fecha1'] = $row['fecha_inicio'];
                    $fechas['fecha2'] = $row['fecha_final'];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {echo 'Excepción general: '.$e->getMessage();}
        catch (PDOException $e) {echo 'Excepción PDO: '.$e->getMessage();}

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($msg === 'getFechas') {
                // Justo aquí devuelvo al cliente el jSON con las fechas obtenidas de la BD
                $client->send(json_encode($fechas));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No realizo respuesta ya que no puedo probar ahora mismo, pero en tu archivo Fechas.php, el bucle foreach al final del metodo onMessage, reemplazalo por if ($msg === 'getFechas') {
    $from->send(json_encode($fechas));
}

Comment: Perfecto, @Israel, sí funciona!